# How to get table Id by .closest()?

Tags: jquery

Based on the example below, I would like to retrieve the id of the parent table. Why is there no problem with DIV Id ?

In console, I get undefined for the two first logs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var f = $("span").closest("table.outherTabClass").attr("id");
  console.log(f);
  var g = $("span").closest("table.innerTabClass").attr("id");
  console.log(g);
  var h = $("span").closest(".firstLevelDivClass").attr("id");
  console.log(h);
  var i = $("span").closest("div").attr("id");
  console.log(i);

});
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="firstLevelDivId" class="firstLevelDivClass">
    <table id = "outherTabId" class ="outherTabClass">
      <table id = "innerTabId" class ="innerTabClass">
        <div id ="secondLevelDivId">
            <div id ="thirdLevelDivId">
              <span>spanText</span>
           </div>
        </div>
      </table>
      </table>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can not have table inside table to start with...

Comment: this is just simplification ...  I have table  and some child tables as an rows ( TR ) expansion

Comment: This is just invalid.  Has your question been answered?  If not, edit your question to make it answerable.  Or, mark the answer given as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because your `table` HTML is invalid. Content within the table needs to be within `td`, within `tr`, within either `thead`, `tbody` or `tfoot`.

With that corrected, the code works fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var f = $("span").closest("table.outherTabClass").prop("id");
  console.log(f);
  
  var g = $("span").closest("table.innerTabClass").prop("id");
  console.log(g);
  
  var h = $("span").closest(".firstLevelDivClass").prop("id");
  console.log(h);
  
  var i = $("span").closest("div").prop("id");
  console.log(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstLevelDivId" class="firstLevelDivClass">
  <table id="outherTabId" class="outherTabClass">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table id="innerTabId" class="innerTabClass">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="secondLevelDivId">
                    <div id="thirdLevelDivId">
                      <span>spanText</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```